# JPA expression to delete the records based on the entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to delete the records from the database based on the entities.
I have List, which I am passing as a parameter to the JPA repository delete method.
But I am getting the below Exception:

> **No property delete found for the type StudentEntity!**

Table schema:

> studentId | studentName | studentRollNo | address

Student Entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@IdClass( PK.class )
@Table("student_data", schema= "public")
public class StudentEntity{

 @Id
 @Column("studentId")
 private Integer studentId;

 @Id
 @Column("studentName")
 private String studentName;

 @Id
 @Column("studentRollNo")
 private Integer studentRollNo;

 @Column("address")
 private String address;
}
```

Composite key:

```
public class PK implements Serializable{ 
 
     private Integer studentId;
     private String studentName;
     private Integer studentRollNo;
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepo extends JpaRepository<StudentEntity, PK>{

  @Transactional
  @Modifying
  int delete(@Param("tobeDeletedEntities") List<StudentEntity> tobeDeletedEntities);

}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to write that. JpaRepository already has that functionality.

[JpaRepository.deleteInBatch(Iterable entities)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#deleteInBatch-java.lang.Iterable-)

Just call:

```
studentRepo.deleteInBatch(listOfStudentsToDelete);
```